# Remove Accounts from Profile

Tags: support

How do I remove a Stack Exchange account from my profile?  Suppose I added an account that I now want to remove. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to remove you account from the list (but still maintain the account) or do you want delete the account completely?

Comment: if you can browse to my profile by clicking on my username, then you will notice an account "Computational Science" listed under Accounts to the left at the bottom of the page. I just want to remove that "Computational Science" account. I hope you get it now! :)

Comment: doesn't matter which one, so unfortunately that doesn't clear it up.  "Remove" and "Delete" have slightly different meanings in this context.  Here "Remove" means "I would like to keep the account, but I don't want to see it in my list of accounts in my profile".  "Delete" means, I don't want the account anymore at all.  You keep saying "Remove" but I think you mean "Delete".  If it is "Delete" then see the duplicate question for instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have never voted or posted, then you'll see a `delete` link on your profile page (next to the `edit` link).

If you have posted or voted, edit the "About Me" section of your profile: change the content into "please delete me". Then, go to the contact page (in the footer of the page), and request deletion of your account.

**Note:** deletion of your account is irreversible!

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 0):

That is a job of the Stack Exchange team. You cannot do that by yourself; if you are a new user, lets say no votes and no answer or question then you can see a delete option in the edit flair menu of your profile. But if you have activity, then you'll have to go to your profile and request for deletion.

First you'll need to go to your profile, there you'll need to edit the *About me* section 
 and write `please delete me` there. Then go to contact the team and they'll have the job handled for you. It might take some time, lets say the working hours.

Contact them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact); once you're done editing the *About me* section.

Comment: Thank you for your time, appreciated. Thanks! :)